# AsyncTask with ListView

Tags: android

I am using a customListAdapter ( extends BaseAdapter) in my application. I have used this adapter inside a ListFragment.

For prototyping I have hard-coded some values in a string array and used those to populate the lists. I am overriding getView and returning the view after inflating.

Now I need to get some data from my webservice call, which I am planning to do inside an AsyncTask.

What is the recommended way to do this?

**Current Code ( Pseudo )**

```
public class customListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View MyconvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflating view 
    // Other view operations
    return MyconvertView;
  }

  class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<params,progress ,Result > {

  @Override
  protected View doInBackground(... params) {
  }


  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(View result) {

        }
  }
 }
}
```

**Modification required:**

Option 1:

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View MyconvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflating view 
    // Other view operations

    return new SomeTask.execute(); // should return the view , the onPostExecute of SomeTask should return this. 
  }
```

Option 2:

Please suggest.

Comment: `new SomeTask.execute()` does not return a view. What does your asynctask do?

Comment: I was just writing the pseudo, if I make the onPostExecute to return a view it should work right?

Comment: no you can't. you can't return values. but your return statement must be a view. I am curious as to what your asynctask does. Is your asynctask an inner class of your adapter class or is it a different class?

Comment: @Raghunandan I actually want to know where exactly I should process my webservice call. And how should I pass the processed data to view. My idea was to process the asyncTask, get the data, inflate the view, then retrun the view. Is it the correct way?

Comment: getView: check if view already loaded (somewhere hold reference) and return it, otherwise view-stub/loading image/... - onPostExecute: create view with data, save view to the references, notifyDataSetChanged. - ?

Comment: @John without knowing what your doing its difficult to tell what to do. but i am sure you can't return view like `return new SomeTask.execute()`.

Comment: There is a good example of retrieving data over HTTP here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask3

Comment: @Raghunandan I am getting some json data from server on asyncTask, I need this to be populated on my view.

Comment: @John first get the data from server and then store it in a list. now pass the list to the adapter class and use the same to populate your listview

Comment: @Raghunandan so instead of calling the webservice from adapter , I should do it from my fragment/activity and pass the processed data to adapter? Am I right?

Comment: @John that would be better. yes it will work

Comment: @Raghunandan could you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502653/send-message-to-calling-listfragment-from-custom-adapter/18502991?noredirect=1#18502991

Answer (score 1):

In PostExecute method of Async Task, call method

```
list.setAdapter(data);
```

So when you get all data, it will be set in list..

Comment: Beacause AsyncTask never return any value