# send message to Calling listFragment from Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a ListFragment , which will display a list of news feed items.

I'm doing an asyncTask to get 20 feeds initially, then I need to do another call to get next 20 feeds , only if the user has done reading first 20.

I.e My Adapter should notify my fragment that it needs next feeds.

This is my present code (AsyncTask of myListFragment) .

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {


    List<PublicFeed> feedItemsList = (List<PublicFeed>) result;

    listener = new ScrollListener();
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(listener);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(2);


    myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, listener,
            feedItemsList);
    setListAdapter(myCustomAdapter);


}
```

- Is this the right way of implementation ( practice ) ?
- The code is working fine now. I'm able to get 20 feeds and display them. But I don't know how do I notify the FeedFragment for next AsyncTask Call From myCustomAdapter?
- once I receve such a call, I can do the asyncTask from myFragment, and update the dataset. Then call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter.

Please review. And suggest an implementation.

Thank YOU

**EDIT -1**

my `CustomAdapter`extends `BaseAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your adapter's constructor so that you can pass the reference of your fragment to your adapter. Then you can make a callback to your fragment's methods from your adapter.

Comment: How can i pass the ref of my fragment to adapter?  myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, listener,
            feedItemsList, REFERENCE TO THIS FRAGMENT);

REFERENCE TO THIS FRAGMENT--> How can i make it?

Comment: myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, listener, feedItemsList, this);  In your adapter, call back using fragment.callback(); where callback() is a public method accessible from your adapter.

Comment: while myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, listener, feedItemsList, this); I'm on my asyncTask. So this will refer to asynctask object